# How to add floating action button that stick to another widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, button, maps, floating-action-button

I am trying to add floating action button that stick into another widget..
here is part of my code..

```
Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
      child: GoogleMap(
        mapType: MapType.normal,
        initialCameraPosition: init,
        markers: ...
        circles: ...,
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
          _controller = controller;
        },
      ),
    );
```

I put my Maps screen inside Container... but I want to add floating action button that stick into my maps screen.. is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a `Stack` widget to achieve what you want.

Check the code below. It works perfectly fine:

```
 // use a stack widget
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            GoogleMap(
              mapType: MapType.normal,
              initialCameraPosition: init,
              markers: ...
              circles: ...,
              onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                _controller = controller;
              },
            ),
            // align it to the bottom center, you can try different options too (e.g topLeft,centerLeft)
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
              // add your floating action button
              child: FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Icon(Icons.map),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

OUTPUT

[image]

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: it works well like what I want.. thank you very much for your help :D

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Stack`

```
 Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Align(
          alignment:Alignment.center,//change this as you need
          child:MyGoogleMap()
         ),
        Align(
          alignment:Alignment.bottomCenter,//change this as you need
          child:FloatingActionButton(...)
         ),
        ],
      ),
```